# method access on object instantiation in C++

Tags: c++, inline

In main function, I have called the function send in two ways. I would like to know what is difference between the both. Which constructors are called, how the data is copied in both the cases? I get different value for data in send when I called it in first way. It got resolved when I removed inline for OneClass(OneClass *).

```
#include <iostream>
class OneClass{

 const void *data;
 public:
  inline OneClass(const void *inData);

  OneClass(const OneClass &in){
         data = in.data;
   }

   static OneClass create(const unsigned &in);
   void send();
};

OneClass OneClass::create(const unsigned &in){
   return OneClass(&in);
}

inline OneClass::OneClass(const void *inData):data(inData){
}

void OneClass::send(){
   std::cout<<"send: "<<*((int*)data)<<"\n";
}


main()
{
  int var = 100;
  OneClass one = OneClass::create(var);
  one.send();//I get different value than 100 in cout(On windriver 64bit)

  OneClass::create(var).send();

}
```

Comment: Maybe thinking at the last line as `(one = OneClass::create(100)).send();` can help, even though they are not exactly the same for it doesn't happen to assign anything to `one` the way you wrote it.

Comment: Both are broken because the constructor is broken. Think of the address you take in the constructor. Whose object is that address?

Comment: I'd have thought it would cast the 100 int to a temporary 100 unsigned, then run with that. When you call send, it's picking the address of the unsigned which was temporary so no longer exists...

Comment: void* is something you should use so seldom you forget it exists.  If you find yourself using void* there is probably a problem with your thought process and design.  What if I passed in a pointer to a vector or a map as a void*?  Your send function would implode and most likely bring your program down.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860626/what-are-void-pointers-for-in-c

Answer (score 4):

Which constructors are called and what is copied is irrelevant. You have undefined behaviour. Inline declaration is also irrelevant, it just happens to be something that changes the undefined behaviour.

The cause for the undefined behaviour is here:

```
OneClass OneClass::create(const unsigned &in){
   return OneClass(&in); // <-- here you take the address of the referenced integer
}
```

Ok, so you take address of an object. Why is that bad? Because of this:

```
OneClass::create(100);
```

Integer literal was bound to the reference `in`. When you bind a literal to a reference (which must be `const`) a temporary is created. The temporary object no longer exists after the call to `create` ends. The address was stored in a member variable and using it later results in undefined behaviour.

However, in the second case:

```
OneClass::create(100).send();
```

The `send()` is called within the same full expression where the temporary was created. Therefore the temporary still exists and the pointer inside the object is still valid and you don't get undefined behaviour.

Since the instance of `OneClass` stores address of an object, you must make sure that any object whose address it stores exists longer than the instance. You should probably change the type of parameter of `create` to a pointer so that the caller knows what's going on and won't try to pass a literal.

---

Edit: Update

If the parameter is an `int` variable, rather than a literal, the above still applies because a temporary is created when `int` is bound to `const unsigned&`. If you changed the parameter type to `const int&` as well as used a variable that's in scope when the pointer is used, then the behaviour would be defined.

Comment: void* should never be used when common sense programming will suffice.  I've worked at many places where void* is not only forbidden (think safety critical anything) but the mere mention of it in an interview will get your resume trashed.  If you are using void* you should have a very, very good reason to do so because that pointer can point to absolutely anything can lead to undefined behavior and massive headaches as you and/or your unfortunate teammates try to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: @soulsabr If you need to implement your interface in C, then `void*` can be pretty much necessary. But in pure C++, I agree that it should be avoided. That's irrelevant in the context of this question, though. If you read the question and the answer carefully, you'll find that I don't recommend using `void` pointers specifically. That's just what Srikanth uses, and I'm recommending that they don't hide their use of pointers in general. I've updated my answer to be clearer about that.

Comment: OK, the updated answer makes more sense.  Before hand it looked like you were advocating void*.

Comment: @user2079303  Thanks for the reply. I am facing this undefined behavior only with int datatype. no issues with other data types like user defined structs, classes. and why it is working when I removed inline for constructor.

Comment: @user2079303  And besides this, what is difference between the two ways I called send?

Comment: @Srikanth no, you do get undefined behaviour with *all* datatypes, if you pass a temporary. Not just int. It appeared to work, when you removed inline because you were unlucky. The difference with the two ways to call send is that in second case, the call to send is part of the same expression where the temporary was created, so the temporary still exists and therefore there is no undefined behaviour in that case. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @user2079303 Thanks. I get this behavior not only with literals but with local variables also(I updated my code in question). So the pointer 'data' ultimately points to the local variable 'var' in stack which should exist after the call 'create'(Until end of the block 'var' is created). Does my analysis miss anything?

Comment: @Srikanth I updated the answer. That variable would indeed exist, but it doesn't matter in this case because you bind it to a `const unsigned&`. Since the type is different (but convertible), a converted temporary is created and the address of that temporary is stored in the member. To get defined behaviour, also change the parameter to match the variable so that no temporary is created.